# Using pre-signed URLs for S3 complete_multipart_upload operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 multi-part uploads with pre-signed URLs.

Uploading the parts with pre-signed URLs (`upload_part` operation) works fine.
For technical reasons, I also have to complete the multi-part upload using a pre-signed URL (`complete_multipart_upload` operation).

In my python code, I generate the URL as follows:

```
url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
    'complete_multipart_upload',
    Params={
        'Bucket': self.bucket_name, 'Key': key, 'UploadId': upload_id,
        'MultipartUpload': {'Parts': parts_param}
    },
    ExpiresIn=PRESIGNED_URLS_EXPIRATION_SECONDS
)
```

The generated URL seems to contain `Bucket`, `Key` and `UploadId`, but is crucially missing the `MultipartUpload` parameter which contains the list of parts.
I checked the format of `parts_param` for correctness - I was previously using it without pre-signed URLs.

```
https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>?uploadId=<upload_id>&AWSAccessKeyId=<upload_id>&Signature=<signature>&Expires=<expires>
```

Is passing the `MultipartUpload` dictionary not supported by pre-signed URLs?

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the API reference ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CompleteMultipartUpload.html ), 'CompleteMultipartUpload' is not a parameter but part of the body. So it should not be included in the generate_presigned_url call.

With this code (MultipartUpload is removed from Params + CompleteMultipartUpload passed in body), it should work :

```
signed_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='complete_multipart_upload',
                                       Params={'Bucket': self.bkt, 'Key':key,
                                               'UploadId': upload_id},
                                       ExpiresIn=3600,
                                       HttpMethod='POST')

def to_xml(multi_parts):
    s = '<CompleteMultipartUpload>\n'
    for part in multi_parts:
        s += '  <Part>\n'
        s += '    <PartNumber>%d</PartNumber>\n' % part["PartNumber"]
        s += '    <ETag>%s</ETag>\n' % part["ETag"]
        s += '  </Part>\n'
    s += '</CompleteMultipartUpload>'
    return s

res = requests.post(signed_url, data=to_xml(parts)
```

Comment: Amazingly, this actually works.

Answer (score -1):

Referring to github for example, seems you need to call create_multipart_upload first. https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2305.

```
import boto3
import requests

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
max_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024 #you can define your own size

res = s3.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
upload_id = res['UploadId']

# please note this is for only 1 part of the file, you have to do it for all parts and store all the etag, partnumber in a list 

parts=[]
signed_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='upload_part',Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': key, 'UploadId': upload_id, 'PartNumber': part_no})

with target_file.open('rb') as f:
      file_data = f.read(max_size) #here reading content of only 1 part of file 

res = requests.put(signed_url, data=file_data)

etag = res.headers['ETag']
parts.append({'ETag': etag, 'PartNumber': part}) #you have to append etag and partnumber of each parts  

#After completing for all parts, you will use complete_multipart_upload api which requires that parts list 
res = s3.complete_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, MultipartUpload={'Parts': parts},UploadId=upload_id)
```

Comment: I do call `create_multipart_upload` first (i have a valid upload ID). In any case, create pre-signed URLs is a local operation, so no way for the SDK to validate correctness anyway. But thanks a bunch for the issue link, will ask there as well.